# Redirecting to path shows : TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redirect, hyperlink, react-router

i am redirecting to a page after sucessfull response , url is changing and also a call to controller is executing which returns data, but when it is rendering on the page it shows:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

48 | var createPath = exports.createPath = function createPath(location) {

> 49 |   var pathname = location.pathname,
>     50 |       search = location.search,
>     51 |       hash = location.hash;
>     52 |

at node_modules/history/PathUtils.js:49

Answer (score 1):

Access pathname only when it is available. You have to put one condition.

```
var pathname = location && location.pathname;
```

It will access pathname only when it is available.